# How to retrieve specific data from an XML file using ASP.NET

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, list

I managed to retrieve all of my data from my XML and display it on my site (works properly). However, I do not want to display every single data that I retrieved.

I only want to get and display some specific values such as Customer -> Id, Name, Address and ShippingAddress -> Id, Name and Address (I have a list based on the xml that I have).

XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Response>
  <Result>
    <TotalCount>1</TotalCount>
    <Customer>
      <field name="Id" value="1234" />
      <field name="Name" value="Dr. Strange" />
      <field name="Address" value="122 New York" />
      <field name="Address2" value="" />
      <field name="Phone" value="3333333333" />
      <field name="ZipCode" value="V5C 6N5" />
      <ShippingAddresses>
        <ShippingAddress>
          <field name="Id" value="456" />
          <field name="Name" value="Wong" />
          <field name="Address" value="122 Drive" />
          <field name="Address2" value="" />
          <field name="ZipCode" value="V5C 6N5" />
       </ShippingAddress>
    </ShippingAddresses>
    </Customer>
  </Result>
  <Errors />
</Response>
```

CustomerController.cs

```
XmlNodeList customerNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("// Customer");
List<CustomerViewModel> customerList = new List<CustomerViewModel>();
CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel();

foreach (XmlNode node in customerNodes)
{ 
  XmlNodeList fieldNodes = node.SelectNodes("field");
  foreach (XmlNode fieldNode in fieldNodes)
  {
    string attrName = fieldNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
    string attrValue = fieldNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
    if (customer.GetType().GetProperty(attrName) != null)
    {
      customer.GetType().GetProperty(attrName).SetValue(customer, attrValue);
    }
  }
  customerList.Add(customer);
}
```

CustomerViewModel.cs

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Currently, my `customerList` contains everything and I can display each value. I just need to display selected information.

Note: I just trimmed my XML file, so it is easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

classes should be

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<ShippingAddress> ShippingAddresses { get; set; }
    }
    public class ShippingAddress
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

and logic should be

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("// Customer");
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                XmlNodeList fieldNodes = node.SelectNodes("field");
                foreach (XmlNode fieldNode in fieldNodes)
                {
                    string attrName = fieldNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                    string attrValue = fieldNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
                    if (customer.GetType().GetProperty(attrName)!=null)
                    {
                        customer.GetType().GetProperty(attrName).SetValue(customer, attrValue);
                    }
                }
                XmlNodeList shippingNodes = node.SelectNodes("ShippingAddresses/ShippingAddress");
                List<ShippingAddress> ShippingAddresses = new List<ShippingAddress>();
                foreach (XmlNode shippingNode in shippingNodes)
                {
                    ShippingAddress ShippingAddress = new ShippingAddress();
                    XmlNodeList shippingFieldNodes = shippingNode.SelectNodes("field");
                    foreach (XmlNode shippingFieldNode in shippingFieldNodes)
                    {
                        string attrName = shippingFieldNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                        string attrValue = shippingFieldNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
                        if (ShippingAddress.GetType().GetProperty(attrName) != null)
                        {
                            ShippingAddress.GetType().GetProperty(attrName).SetValue(ShippingAddress, attrValue);
                        }
                    }
                    ShippingAddresses.Add(ShippingAddress);
                }
                customer.ShippingAddresses = ShippingAddresses;
                customers.Add(customer);
            }
```

Updated

You should put `CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel();` in `foreach` loop of `CustomerController.cs` as given below

CustomerController.cs

```
XmlNodeList customerNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("// Customer");
List<CustomerViewModel> customerList = new List<CustomerViewModel>();

foreach (XmlNode node in customerNodes)
{ 
  CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel();
  XmlNodeList fieldNodes = node.SelectNodes("field");
  foreach (XmlNode fieldNode in fieldNodes)
  {
    string attrName = fieldNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
    string attrValue = fieldNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
    if (customer.GetType().GetProperty(attrName) != null)
    {
      customer.GetType().GetProperty(attrName).SetValue(customer, attrValue);
    }
  }
  customerList.Add(customer);
}
```

Update For your cshtml query

1) ShippingAddress Model

```
public class ShippingAddress
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

2) CustomerViewModel.cs

```
public class CustomerViewModel{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public List<ShippingAddress> ShippingAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

3) cshtml

```
@model CustomerViewModel
.
.
.
.
@foreach(var shippingAddress in Model.ShippingAddresses)
{
    <label>@shippingAddress.Name</label>
}
```

Comment: Hi @Trimantra, thank you for this. It helped me a lot. But another question, If the TotalCount is 3, it keeps on overwriting the first two datas, and just printing the last data 3 times. For instance, if I have ID = 123 | 1234 | 12345, it will print 12345 three times.

Comment: @Shaun can you edit your question with the latest code (after applying my solution)?

Comment: Hi @Trimantra, I edited already the CustomerController. Just ignore the shippingAddress for now. I still have the same problem said above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Shaun I have updated my answer please go through the updated part and check, it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Trimantra. Another question, how can my cshtml recognize my shippingAddress name? I tried model.ShippingAddress.Name and model.Name and it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shaun welcome, I have updated my answer for the question as `Update For your cshtml query` block, check that it will help you.